# Access history html in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit

Does chrome also store some of the html code of previously visited webpages? Can I access them somehow? I would like to recover some html of a website I had accesses yesterday, it now got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. That would be kind of a security leak (if a remote website could access it). It would be worse than the whole Refferer thing.